# prevent cookies from login.microsoftonline.com - ADAL

Tags: azure, oauth, adal.js

I am developing a healthcare related web app and part of HIPPA compliance is that public available web apps need to enforce certain log-out behaviors. One such requirement is that when the users clicks "logout" in the app they must be logged out. Relying on the user to close the browser to clear session storage is not an option.

I am using ADAL-js with angular to handle auth for my app. When you log into the app login.microsoftonline.com stores cookies. As a result if you navigate back to the app you are auto logged back in without being prompted for credentials. That violate the requirement described above. If you use the dev tools in chrome to delete the cookies for that host the problem goes away.

Does anyone know of a way with the Azure AD Oauth service to enforce this more strict requirement?

Answer (score 3):

We ended up opening a  bug against Azure AD with Microsoft. They have since deployed a fix. This all occurred earlier this year. So this update is a bit late.

Comment: Can you share how one would clear the cookies for the login?

Comment: You can't really clear them as the refresh token is stored under the login.microsoftonline.com site. I think that you can now disable the "Keep me signed in" check box under the company branding portion of management portal for your directory. That might get you close to what you need.  Can you share more about what you are looking to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

ADAL.js exposes a couple of functions **clearCacheForResource()** and **clearCache()** in the **adalAuthenticationService** Service. After calling **adalAuthenticationService.logout()**, you can clear the browser cache by calling the above functions. They should clear the cookies.
You can also try using the **$cookieService** provided AngularJS, for better control on the cookies.